# Shared_ptr Implementation with Derived class Awareness

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

Another shared_ptr implementation. My main idea was to write it in a way you could do:

```
MySharedPtr derivedPt(new derived());
MySharedPtr<base> basePt(move(derivedPt));
basePt.reset();
```

where the derived class is destroyed properly without a virtual destructor. I did not find a similar one so thought to try and write one.

```
namespace details {
template<typename T>
class DefaultDeleter {
public:
    void operator()(T* p) {
        delete p;
    }
};

struct ControlBlock_base {
    explicit ControlBlock_base(size_t refCounter):refCounter(refCounter) {}
    //not sure if there is some way to avoid void* maybe std::any as it looks a bit dirty.
    virtual void deletePtr(void* t) = 0;
    size_t refCounter;
};

template<typename T>
struct ControlBlock: public ControlBlock_base {

    template<typename Deleter = details::DefaultDeleter<T>>
    ControlBlock(size_t refCounter, Deleter d = {}) :ControlBlock_base(refCounter), deleter(d) {
    }

    void deletePtr(void* t) override {
        deleter(static_cast<T*>(t));
    }

    function<void(T*)> deleter;
};
}

template<typename T>
class MySharedPtr {
    using ControlBlock_base = details::ControlBlock_base;
    template<typename T>
    using ControlBlock = details::ControlBlock<T>;
    template<typename k>
    friend class MySharedPtr;
public:
MySharedPtr() = default;

template<typename Deleter = details::DefaultDeleter<T>>
MySharedPtr(T* p, Deleter d = {}) :payload(p) {
    if (p != nullptr) {
        cb = new ControlBlock<T>(1, d);
    }
}

MySharedPtr(const MySharedPtr& other) : payload(other.payload), cb(other.cb) {
    if (cb) {
        cb->refCounter++;
    }
}

template <typename U>
    requires derived_from<remove_cvref_t<U>, remove_cvref_t<T>>
MySharedPtr(const MySharedPtr<U>& other): payload(other.payload),cb(other.cb) {
    if (cb) {
        cb->refCounter++;
    }
}

MySharedPtr(MySharedPtr&& other) noexcept {
    swap(other);
}

template<typename U>
    requires derived_from<remove_cvref_t<U>, remove_cvref_t<T>>
MySharedPtr(MySharedPtr<U>&& other) noexcept {
    swap(other);
}

MySharedPtr& operator=(MySharedPtr&& other) noexcept {
    return moveAssignment(move(other));
}

template<typename U>
    requires derived_from<remove_cvref_t<U>, remove_cvref_t<T>>
MySharedPtr& operator=(MySharedPtr<U>&& other) noexcept {
    return moveAssignment(move(other));
}

MySharedPtr& operator=(const MySharedPtr& other) {
    return copyAssignment(other);
}


template<typename U>
    requires derived_from<remove_cvref_t<U>,remove_cvref_t<T>>
MySharedPtr& operator=(const MySharedPtr<U>& other) {
    return copyAssignment(other);
}

~MySharedPtr() {
    if (cb) {
        decrement_destructor();
    }
}


template<typename Deleter = details::DefaultDeleter<T>>
void reset(T* payload = nullptr, Deleter d = {}) {
    MySharedPtr other(payload, d);
    swap(other);
}

explicit operator bool() const { return payload != nullptr; }

bool operator==(const MySharedPtr& o) const { return payload == o.payload; }
bool operator!=(const MySharedPtr& o) const { return *this != o; }

T* get() { return payload; }
T& operator*() { return *payload; }
T* operator->() { return payload; }


private:
template<typename U>
MySharedPtr& copyAssignment(const MySharedPtr<U>& other) {
    if (cb != other.cb) {
        MySharedPtr tmp(other);
        swap(tmp);
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename U>
MySharedPtr& moveAssignment(MySharedPtr<U>&& other) {
    MySharedPtr tmp(move(other));
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}

void decrement_destructor() {
    cb->refCounter--;
    if (cb->refCounter == 0) {
        cb->deletePtr(payload);
        delete cb;
    }
}

template<typename U>
void swap(MySharedPtr<U>& other) {
    std::swap(cb, other.cb);
    T* tmp{ payload };
    payload = static_cast<T*>(other.payload);
    other.payload = static_cast<U*>(payload);
}

T* payload{ nullptr };
ControlBlock_base* cb{ nullptr };
};
```

Example program/test of the above:

```
class base {
public:
    base() = default;
    ~base() {
        cout << "base destructor";
    }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() = default;
    ~derived() {
        cout << "derived destructor";
    }
};

int main() {

    MySharedPtr derivedPt(new derived());
    MySharedPtr<base> basePt(move(derivedPt));
    basePt.reset();//delete via derived destructor

    int* t = new int(2);
    int* z = new int(2);
    auto customDestructor = [](int* t) {};
    MySharedPtr<int> sharedWithCustomDel(t, customDestructor);
    MySharedPtr<int> copyAssignTest;
    copyAssignTest = sharedWithCustomDel;//copy assignment
    copyAssignTest.reset(new int(3));//should call cD destructor
    MySharedPtr<int> moveConstructed(move(copyAssignTest));//move constructor
    MySharedPtr<int> copyConstructed(moveConstructed);//copy const

    MySharedPtr<int> moveAssigned;
    moveAssigned = move(moveConstructed);//move assign
    assert(*moveAssigned == 3);
}
```

Comment: Is the intent here to implement the `std::shared_ptr` interface, at least partially? Or is that not a goal?

Comment: Added thank you for suggestion. Yes I think it has most of the main api implemented

Comment: Have you tested this? `bool operator!=(const MySharedPtr& o) const { return *this != o; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overall

Bug. In your `!=` test means it will recursively call itself forever!

No other major issues.

- You could do something about moving the `Deleter` in the control block rather than copying.
- Your constructor could be improved:
  Make it explicit.
  Allowing `nullptr`

Personally, I found your indentation style hard to read. I assume you are conforming to your teams standards though (please make sure you are).

### Code Review

I vaguely see potentially why you want to break `ControlBlock_base` and `ControlBlock` into two separate classes. **BUT** I don't see any specific use cases for it currently. Uncomplicate your code and reduce this to a single class until you have a use case where this is something you use.

```
struct ControlBlock_base {....};

template<typename T>
struct ControlBlock: public ControlBlock_base {...};
```

Also all your shared pointer classes now contain two pointers. Why not have the control block also contain the pointer to the managed memory. Then some of the code could be moved into here as well and reduce the complexity of your main class.

---

What happens if the `new` fails?

```
template<typename Deleter = details::DefaultDeleter<T>>
MySharedPtr(T* p, Deleter d = {}) :payload(p) {
    if (p != nullptr) {
        cb = new ControlBlock<T>(1, d);
    }
}
```

You have just leaked the pointer you were asked to look after.

I would also mark this constructor `explicit` to prevent accidentally creating these objects where you don't expect to!

```
  void doWorkPart1(MySharedPtr<int> data);
  void doWorkPart2(MySharedPtr<int> data);

  int main()
  {
       int*   data = new int(5);
       doWorkPart1(data);      // parameter takes ownership and deletes on return
       doWorkPart1(data);      // Here you are passing a freed pointer.

       // It would be nice to prevent this kind of accidental call
  }
```

Also you don't allow for construction with `nullptr`. Sure it is rare, but it would be nice if you could explicitly use `nullptr` without having to do anything special.

```
  MySharedPtr<int>  value(nullptr); // fails to compile.
```

---

I would consider this old school.

```
MySharedPtr& operator=(MySharedPtr&& other) noexcept {
    return moveAssignment(move(other));
}

MySharedPtr& operator=(const MySharedPtr& other) {
    return copyAssignment(other);
}

template<typename U>
MySharedPtr& copyAssignment(const MySharedPtr<U>& other) {
    if (cb != other.cb) {
        MySharedPtr tmp(other);
        swap(tmp);
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename U>
MySharedPtr& moveAssignment(MySharedPtr<U>&& other) {
    MySharedPtr tmp(move(other));
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

The simpler technique is to treat both `copy` and `move` assignment the same way. Let the compiler work out the details.

```
MySharedPtr& operator=(MySharedPtr other) noexcept {
    swap(other);
    return *this;
}
// Sure your copy prevents one increment and decrement and a couple of assignments.
// But the cost of these operations are insignificant compared
// to the cost of branch predication failure. Simpler to do it this way.
```

Notice the parameter is a value. Thus if you pass an r-value reference `other` is created by move otherwise it is created by a copy. Then you simply swap and return a reference to yourself.

So you have achieved the same results as above with a lot fewer lines of code.

---

I think this is slightly error prone.

```
~MySharedPtr() {
    if (cb) {
        decrement_destructor();
    }
}

void decrement_destructor() {
    cb->refCounter--;
    if (cb->refCounter == 0) {
        cb->deletePtr(payload);
        delete cb;
    }
}
```

Before calling `decrement_destructor` you always have to check that `cb` is not `null`. So why not move that check into `decrement_destructor` then everybody can call without the check. This will prevent slip ups in the future.

---

Bug:

```
bool operator!=(const MySharedPtr& o) const { return *this != o; }
```

As mentioned above this is a recursive call to yourself.

Simple Fix (call the operator ==).

```
bool operator!=(const MySharedPtr& o) const { return !(*this == o); }
```

---

Should there not be `const` versions of these functions?

```
T* get() { return payload; }
T& operator*() { return *payload; }
T* operator->() { return payload; }
```

---

Comment: Thank you Martin. Much appreciated. The idea with the assignment operator is great. Will have it in mind. Guess the rule of thumb is if it is light weight class to go for the pass-by-value.  For the base class my main idea was to preserve the derived class type if I have  MySharedPtr<base> instance(new derived()) so I can delete it via a pointer to derived instead of base to avoid the virtual destructor idiom similarly to what the actual  shared_ptr achieves.

Comment: The pointer to the managed memory cannot be moved into the control block, because a valid pointer conversion could have a different object representation, and both the original and the converted pointer must share the same control block. At least not without an even-more-complicated adapter to perform a conversion (sequence of arbitrary length) on demand.